# How to get a flat JSON from a nested one?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a nested JSON and I need `"Max"` & `"Remaining"` percentage values from it.

This is sample formula I am thinking of `100-(Remaining/Max)*100=(Value)`

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances":
      {
        "Max": 5,
        "Remaining": 3
    },
    "DailyApiRequests": 
      {

        "Max":15000,"Remaining":14108
      }
}
```

This is the JSON output.

I need to add the % value to the key

Sample output:

```
{
    "ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances":40,(%value) 100-(5/3)*100
    "DailyApiRequests": 5.95(%value) 100-(14108/15000)*100

}
```

Workarounds:

- Tried to do make it a flat JSON and worked but didn't helped me
- Worked on converting JSON into CSV and tried some but it was hard

Can someone suggest the best to do this? If possible provide some examples. Some help would also be appreciated.

Note: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: There are many `"Max"` & `"Remaining"` percentage values in the input JSON. Which ones are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks for asking  for all **"Max"** & **"Remaining"**  Values i need the percentage values

Comment: OK, how do they relate to the output you want?

Comment: I need the percentage of **Max** & **Remaining** Values to be appended  in output

Comment: Even with that update, I still don't understand how the input relates to the output or even what you mean by "appended in output"? Seems like that would imply that the output would have everything in the input **plus** something, but you don't show that in your sample output.

Comment: looking for calculated percentage value in new JSON output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly receive your json and convert it to dictionary

```
import json
input_dict = json.loads(<your received son string>)
```

Then work on the input dict like below through recursive calls:

```
input_dict = {
     "ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances":
       {
         "Max": 200,"Remaining":200
        }, 
     "DailyApiRequests": 
        { 
         "Max": 15000, "Remaining": 14108, 
         "Ant Migration Tool": {"Max": 0, "Remaining": 0},
         "Chatter Desktop": {"Max": 0, "Remaining": 0}, 
         "Chatter Mobile for BlackBerry":
         {"Max": 0, "Remaining": 0},
         "Chemical Equipment And Processing": 
         {"Max": 0,"Remaining": 0}
        } 
     }

def flattenjson(input_dict, odict):
    for ky in input_dict.keys():
        if isinstance(input_dict[ky], dict):
            if set(['Max', 'Remaining']).issubset(input_dict[ky].keys()):
                if input_dict[ky]["Max"] != 0:
                    odict[ky] = 100-(float(input_dict[ky]["Remaining"])/input_dict[ky]["Max"])*100
                else:
                    odict[ky] = 0
            for iky in input_dict[ky].keys():
                if isinstance(input_dict[ky][iky], dict):
                    tmp = {iky : input_dict[ky][iky]}
                    odict = flattenjson(tmp, odict)
    return odict

odict = flattenjson(input_dict, dict())
print json.dumps(odict)
```

`flattenjson` helps you recursively work on to get your desired output for all Max and Remaining entries

Comment: Hi Thanks for the snippet it worked well but I have Some problem in reading the deep nested json of the  output It couldn't read the inner keys I am attaching the link of my input file **https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Y9GEv7rthm7tL6-ejgKYyLAsX_A8hzVwn4zYLRD0xLg/edit**Please Suggest me the changes in the given snippet

Comment: @SrihariNadendla i am able to parse it well and output as well

Answer (score 1):

There is now a Python package for this called `flatten_json`. An introduction is provided [here](https://medium.com/@amirziai/flatten-json-on-python-package-index-pypi-9e4951693a5a).

An example from that page--

In your shell:

```
> pip install flatten_json
```

In your Python console:

```
from flatten_json import flatten
input_dict = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": [{"d": [2, 3, 4], "e": [{"f": 1, "g": 2}]}]
}
print(flatten(input_dict))
```

Results:

```
{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c_0_d_0': 2,
 'c_0_d_1': 3,
 'c_0_d_2': 4,
 'c_0_e_0_f': 1,
 'c_0_e_0_g': 2}
```

I've tested this in both Python 3.6 and 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve nested values using the json library like so:

```
import json
sample_json = '{"ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances":{"Max": 5,"Remaining": 3},"DailyApiRequests": {"Max":15000,"Remaining":14108}}'

jason = json.loads(sample_json)
cagri_max = jason['ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances']['Max']
cagri_rem = jason['ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances']['Remaining']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to flatten the data structure. Just reference that pieces of it you want—so, for example, I think the following does essentially what you want:

```
import json

json_data = {
                "ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances": {
                    "Max": 5,
                    "Remaining": 3
                },
                "DailyApiRequests": {
                    "Max": 15000,
                    "Remaining": 14108
                }
            }

def percentage_values(remaining, maximum):
    return 100 - (float(remaining)/float(maximum)) * 100

# build output dictionary
json_out = {}
for key in json_data:
    value = percentage_values(json_data[key]["Remaining"], json_data[key]["Max"])
    json_out.update([(key, value)])

print(json.dumps(json_out, indent=4))
```

The resulting output showing the contents of `json_out` is:

```
{
    "ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances": 40.0, 
    "DailyApiRequests": 5.9466666666666725
}
```

There are more succinct ways to write this in Python, but they all would do what is done above in a very simple manner.